# marathon/mesos cannot run more than one application

Tags: docker, apache-zookeeper, mesos, marathon

I have three master nodes with marathon/mesos/zookeeper working fine, and one test node with 32 gb ram and 24 cores. When i start an application it is successful for one application when i try to run another application on the same node it hangs out. So i tried running elasticsearch, it is running no errors, second i try to run rabbitmq on the same node, no errors, no warning, just the deployment is stuck in the queue. I have enough resources to satisfy both of the applications. Any ideas?

- Slave mesos resources: http://pastebin.com/7C6jUnnm
- Marathon queue:
  http://pastebin.com/kv8DDisA
- Marathon apps:
  http://pastebin.com/ncrrqNsi

I am running just for testing a "echo" command now, marathon is still not running it.

I can add more stuff if needed.

Comment: Can you post marathon/mesos logs?

Answer (score 0):

There can be various reasons that can lead to an app being stuck in deployment like your machine does not have sufficient resources (not enough RAM/CPU or unavailable port) or some constraints in the app definitions that are not getting fulfilled by the resource offers from mesos.

I would recommend reviewing your app definition for make sure you have the necessary resources and also looking at Marathon logs to get an idea as to why its not accepting offers for the app.

Can you please post the Marathon app JSON for rabbitmq along with your Marathon logs ? I might be able to help you with it.

Comment: i have added some info now.

Comment: Also i am able to run chronos tasks on that node.

Comment: I could not find anything obviously problematic in you app definition (As long as port 10000 is available to be offered on that machine). Marathon logs would be very helpful in debugging this.